# ATPL theoretical course hours per subject

Tags: theory

do someone know what is the hours per subject mandatory for ATPL (A) EASA program. In the Easy Access Rules for Aircrew (PART FCL) it said:

The 750 hours of instruction should be divided in such a way that in each subject the minimum hours are:

(1) Air law 35 hours
(2) Aircraft general knowledge 100 hours
(3) Flight performance and planning 120 hours
(4) Human performance and limitations 35 hours
(5) Meteorology 60 hours
(6) Navigation 90 hours
(7) Operational procedures 25 hours
(8) Principles of flight 55 hours
(9) Communications 20 hours

But there is 14 subjects and there is not the hours separately for each of 14 subjects.